# Items in a 'column count' CSS masonry container - drop shadows splitting across lines

Tags: css, datagrid, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using column count in CSS to give my items a masonry effect.

This is working great, but I have just tried giving the items a slight drop shadow, and if you look at the jsfiddle you will see that at the bottom of the container it appears to have the drop shadows that are clipped from the top of some of the items?

[image: jsfiddle drop shadow issue]

I have tried giving the items a top margin etc to try and stop this, but cannot get it work. Where am I going wrong.

The issue is the three lines under the last items.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3930/

Backup code:

```
.cols {
-moz-column-count:4;
-moz-column-gap: 3%;
-moz-column-width: 25%;
-webkit-column-count:4;
-webkit-column-gap: 3%;
-webkit-column-width: 25%;
column-count: 4;
column-gap: 3%;
column-width: 25%;
}
.item {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
-o-column-break-inside: avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
break-inside: avoid;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
```

Comment: Masonry?  Do you mean a "running bond" pattern where the lines are staggered?

Comment: not too sure to get it. Is this , this kind of thing you try to do ? http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3931/

Comment: Everything works fine, but the drop shadow seems to be breaking to the next line from maybe the last item. So if you look at the picture you can see 3 faint lines under the columns. They shouldnt be there, they are from the drop shadow.

Answer (score 0):

The  `box-shadow`  should not be on the items. Remove it and put it inside on the thumbs

```
.thumbnail {
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4167/)